# How to remove Drush installation

Tags: command-line, command, drush

I installed Drush with sudo apt-get install drush.

How can I remove it now?

Comment: Have you tried "apt-get remove"?

Comment: None of the answers given work for me.  Amazing.  Why is this so hard.

Answer (score 3):

Just had the same prob, installing drush that way will get you something that doesn't work at all...

try this:

> sudo apt-get remove drush

Then install it like this:

```
sudo wget --quiet -O - http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drush-7.x-5.1.tar.gz | sudo tar -zxf - -C /usr/local/share
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/drush/drush /usr/local/bin/drush
sudo drush
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe you can type it:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove drush
```

I would suggest use PEAR chanel to install as mentioned in the official website,
which is easier to update and manage:

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.drush.org
sudo pear install drush/drush
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove it manually:

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/drush.*
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq drush
```

Answer (score 0):

Try >**[this tip](http://www.hackido.com/2009/11/force-uninstall-package-in-debianubuntu.html)**< to force uninstall apps in Debian/Ubuntu. Then, the rest of "removing" drush is just deleting where you installed it to. If you absolutely don't know/can't remember, do a search for "drush" like so:

```
find / -type d -name 'drush' #to find any directories named drush 
find / -type f -name 'drush' #to find any folders named drush
```

This will help you locate the Drush install folder remnants so that you can clean them up before you re-install Drush.

Honestly though, I'd **install Drush manually** the way [lfx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370659/lfx) notes in his comment. The syntax changes between Drush major versions and if you let apt manage this, you could inadvertantly upgrade your Drush install. Also, by controlling your Drush install, you can install different Drush versions for different sites/users by installing each Drush version to a different location and using symbolic links for the user's shell environment.

Comment: In the second line that you suggested you wrote: 
"to find any FOLDERS named drush"

I think that you intended to have written:
"to find any FILES named drush"